# How to use a Material Icons icon within a Primefaces component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, material-design

How to use [Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) within a Primefaces component, example:
`<p:commandButton icon="material-icons-outlined face"/>`
defined using the icon attribute prefixed by `"ui-icon-`.
Because, on the Material Icons website, it is only possible to use this way:

```
<span class="material-icons-outlined">face</span>
```

[Icon Face](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined:face)

The [Primefaces Sapphire Template](https://www.primefaces.org/sapphire/utils.xhtml) shows a conversion option, adapting, and I would like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the source of Saphire you will need to use CSS like this which overrides `ui-icon` etc.

Source: https://www.primefaces.org/sapphire/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-sapphire-blue

**Declare the font face:**

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("/sapphire/javax.faces.resource/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot.xhtml?ln=sapphire-layout");
    /* For IE6-8 */
    src: local("Material Icons"), local("MaterialIcons-Regular"), url("/sapphire/javax.faces.resource/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2.xhtml?ln=sapphire-layout") format("woff2"), url("/sapphire/javax.faces.resource/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff.xhtml?ln=sapphire-layout") format("woff"), url("/sapphire/javax.faces.resource/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf.xhtml?ln=sapphire-layout") format("truetype");
}
```

**Override `ui-icon`**

```css
body .ui-icon {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    text-indent: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    /* Support for Firefox. */
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    /* Support for IE. */
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}

body .material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    /* Preferred icon size */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    /* Support for Firefox. */
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    /* Support for IE. */
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

Then at the bottom of the theme all the ui-icons are delcared like this...

```css
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e:before { content: ""; }
```